# Imbricated for selection in dict (Python)

Tags: python, dictionary, selection

Coming from MATLAB, I am really new to Python and i am still trying to understand its syntax. 
I succeeded in doing what I want but I am sure there is a proper way to do it in only one line...

```
serialsToFind = ['43788273-1', '45788259-2', '87788202']
dataSelection = []
from numpy import linspace
serials = linspace(0,len(data)-1,len(data), dtype='int')
for serialToFind in serialsToFind:
    for serial in serials:
        if data[serial]['SerialNumber'][:8] == serialToFind[:8]:
            dataSelection.append(data[serial])
```

Thanks a lot,

Max

Comment: Do you know what you're doing? Because I sure don't.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't say what `data` is. However, what you probably want is

```
dataSelection = [item for serialToFind in serialsToFind for item in data
    if item['SerialNumber'][:8] == serialToFind[:8]]
```

Note: In general, instead of doing

```
serials = linspace(0,len(data)-1,len(data), dtype='int')
for serial in serials:
```

just do

```
for serial in range(len(data)):
```